# How to get the value from a list + input

Tags: python, list, for-loop, input

So sorry for the vague title but this is my problem.
(I just started this study)

### For example

```
list_1 = [a, b, c, d, e, f]

input_1 = input('question1')
input_2 = input('question2')
```

lets say they chose

```
input_1  = b
input_2 =  f
```

I need something that prints the letters between the 2 chosen ones.
So you would get

```
c
d
e
```

What I tried is using the for statement with an if statement but it didnt work out very well. 
I also need something that checks if input2 is further in the list than input1. I tried with

```
if input_2 > input_1:
     print('yey')
else:
     print('not recognized, automatically f')
     input_2 = list_1[-1]
```

sorry for the beginner question =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want to loop through the list and compare characters like you would numbers.

```
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    if list_1[i] > input_1 and list_1[i] < input_2:
        print list_1[i]
```

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
if input_1 in list_1 and input_2 in list_1:
    print(list_1[list_1.index(input_1)+1:list_1.index(input_2)])
else:
    print('didn't find input_1 or input_2)
```

This?

if you need to auto print the rest of the list from before input_2 or after input_1 you can just add if statements like

```
if input_1 in list_1 and input_2 in list_1:
    print(list_1[list_1.index(input_1)+1:list_1.index(input_2)])
elif input_1 in list_1 and not input_2 in list_1:
    print(list_1[list_1.index(input_1)+1:])
elif not input_1 in list_1 and input_2 in list_1:
    print(list_1[0:list_1.index(input_2)])
else:
    print('didn't find input_1 or input_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`input_1` and `input_2` are elements in the list.

You can use slice in python to get the elements present between the input elements.

```
 index_1 = list_1.index(input_1)
 index_2 = list_l.index(input_2)
 new_list = list_1[index_1:index_2]
 print new_list
```

Comment: This is simple and good for a beginner like me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the list.index() method, you can find documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

In your case, this will look like

```
i1 = list_1.index(input_1)
i2 = list_1.index(input_2)

if i2 > i1:
    print('yey')
```

And then you can use a slice and loop to print the sublist

```
sublist = list_1[i1:i2]
for c in sublist:
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the list and take out indices for each of the inputs then test for the conditions you want. Something like this:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']
input_1  = 'b'
input_2 =  'f'
input_1_index = -1
input_2_index = -1

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] == input_1:
        input_1_index = i
    elif list1[i] == input_2:
        input_2_index = i

if input_1_index == -1 or input_2_index == -1 or input_1_index > input_2_index:
    print('error')

else:
    print(list1[(input_1_index+1):input_2_index])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of what you're trying to do. Make sure alphabet is the whole list of letters and you a way of checking if user input is a string from the alphabet.

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

input_1 = str(input(""))
input_2 = str(input(""))

Input1Pos = alphabet.index(input_1)

Input2Pos = alphabet.index(input_2)

if (Input2Pos > Input1Pos):
    Input1Pos = Input1Pos + 1
    print alphabet[Input1Pos:Input2Pos]

elif (Input2Pos == Input1Pos):
print "There are no characters between these two inputs"
else:
    print "The second input was before the first input"
```